# Logic-Deduction

Tags: propositional-calculus

I have:

Lemma 1$$
\vdash\psi\rightarrow(\lnot\psi\rightarrow\varphi) 
$$
We also have
$$
\{\lnot\varphi\rightarrow\varphi,\lnot\varphi\}\vdash\varphi
$$ and
$$
\{\lnot\varphi\rightarrow\varphi,\lnot\varphi\}\vdash\lnot\varphi
$$
Can anyone explain why this and the lemma gives
$$
\{\lnot\varphi\rightarrow\varphi,\lnot\varphi\}\vdash\lnot(\varphi\rightarrow\varphi)
$$

Logical axioms:
$$
1.\ \ \varphi\rightarrow(\psi\rightarrow\varphi)
$$
$$
2.\ \ (\varphi\rightarrow(\psi\rightarrow\chi))\rightarrow((\varphi\rightarrow\psi)\rightarrow(\varphi\rightarrow\chi))
$$

$$
3.\ \ (\lnot\varphi\rightarrow\lnot\psi)\rightarrow(\psi\rightarrow\varphi)
$$

Inference rule:
$$
4.\ \ MP
$$

Proof lemma:
By axiom 1 we have
$$
\{\psi,\lnot\psi \} \vdash\lnot\varphi\rightarrow\lnot\psi
$$
By axiom 3 we get

$$
\{\psi,\lnot\psi \} \vdash\psi\rightarrow\varphi
$$

But then

$$
\{\psi,\lnot\psi \} \vdash\varphi
$$

2 x the deduction theorem now gives the result.

Comment: How did Lemma 1 get proved?

Comment: see my adds - thanks

Comment: You can substitute any wff for any variable provided that you do so uniformly (either on both sides of the $\vdash$ symbol or throughout the formula on the right hand side).  So, you assume {¬φ→φ,¬φ}.  What does using modus ponens lead to?  What substitutions can you make in Lemma 1 which might lead to ¬(φ→φ)?